# Хостинг для сайта на node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, хостинг

Я сделал сайт пользуюсь фреймворком Express, шаблонизатором Jade и бд MongoDB. Где мне найти хостинг?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Под NoSQL бд, Вы можете использовать хостинг [mlab.com](https://mlab.com/), а вообще наверное лучше воспользоваться VDS - хостингом, настройте под себя все, что необходимо.

Comment: а чем отличается VPS от VDS хостинга ?

Comment: в принципе ничем, единственное в концепции разделения, которая позволяет запускать на виртуальном сервере несколько приложений, но отличия довольно расплывчаты

Answer (score 2):

Посмотрите ещё [heroku](https://www.heroku.com/).

Можно ещё VPS c Linux и там настроить node и mongodb самому

Забыл, тот же Microsoft Azure поддерживает хостинг node и mongodb

Comment: Хероку - это отлично - все им пользуются, но для БД нужно что-то ещё, т. к. их бесплатный вариант вообще не предусматривает хранение данных.